# Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add assets from an external package in my flutter application
as mentioned here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#bundling-of-package-assets

I am getting this `Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml /project/location/<project_name>/packages` even for adding this simple entry which cant be null.

```
  assets:
    - packages/
```

Comment: Can you please try a different directory name? `packages` was reserved in older Dart version. There might be a bug where this wasn't fully removed yet.

Comment: Actually I have added external package in pubspec.yaml which have assets in its lib/ directory.. how do I access those assets??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-images-in-package-dependencies explains how to add assets from dependencies

```
  assets:
    - packages/some_package/backgrounds/background1.png
```

Would add asset `lib/backgrounds/background1.png` from package `some_package`.

Assets from packages do not support adding whole directories yet and you need to add each asset file individually (files from resolution sub-directories are recognized automatically though)

Adding an asset directory also does not support adding a directory tree from the application package. Only all files directly below a listed directory are recognized (again including resolution sub-directories)

Comment: Thanks everything is working fine,  would you like to explain this "(files from resolution sub-directories are recognized automatically though)" with an example,  what is resolution sub-directory?

Comment: It's named resolution-aware image assets in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images (I meant directories like `2.0x`, `3.0x`, ...)

Comment: Ok can I load assets name from  another file e.g. any text file, as I have to add almost 5000 names form non resolution sub-directories and I don't want to add all in my pubpec.yaml

Comment: Currently not as far as I know. Check GitHub issues about related feature requests.It might be better to use some database (key-value store) for that and put all into that to get a single asset file and then read from that file in your app. You might need to copy the asset into a normal file on first app load to be able to access it as file (using `dart:io/File`)

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by:

1. **Moving the assets folder out of the lib folder, that's to the root folder.**
2. **Restarting my editor**
3. **Moving back the assets folder to to lib folder.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that pubspec.yaml is correct (2 spaces for assets and 4 spaces for the subfolders:

--- If unsure, then copy below this line to get the correct indentation ---


  assets: 
    -images/ 
    -assets/

then have a look at the project tree, I have copied the assets and image folders from an older project and by mistake I set them in the wrong place on the project tree (a simple drag & drop can solve the problem in this case) followed by a new packages get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case i'm adding icons like this

assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/icons/

but in my case i have not use any icon in the project and i have remove this line - assets/icons/ in pubspec.yaml after that i have pubget that and i have hot restart apply in my project and this error are resolved