# Create folder using GitHub actions and inject JSON file

Tags: flutter, github, dart, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have 2 secrets in a JSON file which i do not want to push to my GitHub Repo but i need it to build my apk using GitHub actions.

FileName : **app_config.json**

FilePath from Root : **config / app_config.json**

```
{
  "secret1":"abc",
  "secret2" : "def",
}
```

So this is what i came up with :

- **Step 1** : Add it to .gitignore
- **Step 2** : Add the base 64 version of the JSON file to GitHub secrets
- **Step 3** : Add the folder as well as the file [config/app_config.json] at runtime in GitHub actions.

I am performing this in 2 steps:

- **Step 1** : This is a Github action which [converts base 64 to a file](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/base64-to-file)   (APP_CONFIG is the GitHub secret with base 64 version of the json file).

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
   - name: base64-to-file
     id: write_file
     uses: timheuer/base64-to-file@v1.0.3
     with:
       # Name of the file when written to temp location
       fileName: 'app_config.json'
       # The base64 encoded string
       encodedString: ${{ secrets.APP_CONFIG }}
```

- **Step 2** : This is the code i am using to

  (a) Create a folder named "config"

  (b) Move the file from that location (where it was decoded) to the "config" folder

```
 - name: Inject env variables
      run: |
        mkdir -p ${{ github.workspace }}/config
        mv ${{ steps.write_file.outputs.filePath }} ${{ github.workspace }}/config/
```

When i build this workflow , I do not get any error in this part, but later on while i run "Flutter Test" where the tests of the app are run, This folder is not recognized.

**Error:**

```
Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml: /home/runner/work/<my_repo_name>/<my_repo_name>/config/
```

But didn't i just create the Config Folder ? why isn't it recognizing it?

Complete `dart.yml` File

```
name: App PlayStore Release

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  version:
    name: Create version number
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: base64-to-file
      id: write_file
      uses: timheuer/base64-to-file@v1.0.3
      with:
        # Name of the file when written to temp location
        fileName: 'app_config.json'
        # The base64 encoded string
        encodedString: ${{ secrets.APP_CONFIG }}
    - name: Inject env variables
      run: |
        mkdir -p ${{ github.workspace }}/config
        mv ${{ steps.write_file.outputs.filePath }} ${{ github.workspace }}/config/
    - name: Fetch all history for all tags and branches
      run: |
        git config remote.origin.url https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}
        git fetch --prune --depth=10000
    - name: Install GitVersion
      uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0.9.3
      with:
          versionSpec: '5.2.x'
    - name: Use GitVersion
      id: gitversion
      uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.3
    - name: Create version.txt with nuGetVersion
      run: echo ${{ steps.gitversion.outputs.nuGetVersion  }} > version.txt
    - name: Upload version.txt
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: gitversion
        path: version.txt
  build:
    name: Build APK and Create release
    needs: [ version ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Get version.txt
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: gitversion
    - name: Create new file without newline char from version.txt
      run: tr -d '\n' < version.txt > version1.txt
    - name: Read version
      id: version
      uses: juliangruber/read-file-action@v1
      with:
        path: version1.txt
    - name: Update version in YAML
      run: sed -i 's/99.99.99+99/${{ steps.version.outputs.content }}+${{ github.run_number }}/g' pubspec.yaml
    - name: Update KeyStore password in gradle properties
      run: sed -i 's/#{KEYSTORE_PASS}#/${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_PASS }}/g' android/key.properties
    - name: Update KeyStore key password in gradle properties
      run: sed -i 's/#{KEYSTORE_KEY_PASS}#/${{ secrets.KEYSTORE_KEY_PASS }}/g' android/key.properties
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
        flutter-version: '1.17.0'
    - run: flutter pub get
    - run: flutter test
    - run: flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi
    - run: flutter build appbundle
    - name: Create a Release in GitHub
      uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
      with:
        artifacts: "build/app/outputs/apk/release/*.apk,build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab"
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
        tag: ${{ steps.version.outputs.content }}
        commit: ${{ github.sha }}
    - name: Upload app bundle
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: appbundle
        path: build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
  release:
    name: Release app to internal track
    needs: [ build ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Get appbundle from artifacts
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: appbundle
    - name: Release app to internal track
      uses: r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1
      with:
        serviceAccountJsonPlainText: ${{ secrets.PLAYSTORE_ACCOUNT_KEY }}
        packageName: com.notes.ounotes
        releaseFile: app-release.aab
        track: internal
        whatsNewDirectory: distribution/whatsnew
```

Complete **Pubspec.yaml** file

```
name: FSOUNotes
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
# //publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 99.99.99+99

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  fluttertoast: ^4.0.1
  flutter_mailer: ^0.5.1
  open_appstore: ^1.0.2
  share: ^0.6.4+3
  intl: ^0.16.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  cuid: ^0.1.2
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  file_picker: ^1.12.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11
  expansion_tile_card: ^1.0.3
  flutter_typeahead: ^1.8.1
  mime: ^0.9.6+3
  awesome_dialog: ^1.1.3



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  stacked: ^1.6.0
  stacked_hooks: 0.1.1+3
  stacked_services: ^0.4.4+1
  logger: ^0.6.0
  # http request
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  # async package to add additional Cancellable operations
  async: ^2.0.8
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+2
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.6.0
  auto_route: ^0.5.0
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1

  get_it:
  injectable:
  flutter_hooks:
  observable_ish:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner:
  auto_route_generator:
  injectable_generator:
  mockito:

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/images/apnaicon.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/images/pdf.png
   - assets/images/pdf1.png
   - assets/images/link.png
   - assets/images/Applogo.jpg
   - assets/images/apnaicon.png
   - assets/images/1.png
   - assets/images/2.png
   - assets/images/3.png
   - assets/images/4.png
   - assets/images/5.png
   - assets/images/6.png
   - assets/images/7.png
   - assets/images/github-logo.png
   - assets/images/OU_Logo.jpg
   - config/

  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Quicksand
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Custom
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Custom.ttf
        
          
 

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162924/error-unable-to-find-directory-entry-in-pubspec-yaml

Comment: In that Question the user wants to add a file from an external package, in my case the file is being generated in the workflow.

Comment: Are you targetting the directory or the file? Can you post your yaml?

Comment: yaml file added. In the assets im writing config/ which basically means all its contents so i guess that shouldnt be a problem ?

Comment: Check the answer I linked. It says, you have to seperately add each file and can't add directories :)

Comment: I tried but the error is same. "File not found" :(